# Finding connected components of a graph

Tags: python, graph

I have a graph represented using a dict of sets, e.g.

```
graph = {
    0: {1, 2, 3},  # neighbors of node "0"
    1: {0, 2},
    2: {0, 1},
    3: {0, 4, 5},
    4: {3, 5},
    5: {3, 4, 7},
    6: {8},
    7: {5},
    8: {9, 6},
    9: {8}
}
```

I use the following code to find connected components in the graph:

```
def get_connected_components(graph):
    seen = set()
    components = []

    for node in graph:
        if node not in seen:
            component = []
            nodes = {node}

            while nodes:
                node = nodes.pop()
                seen.add(node)
                component.append(node)
                nodes.update(graph[node].difference(seen))
            components.append(component)

    return components

print(get_connected_components(graph))  # [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], [6, 8, 9]]
```

Is there a better way to do this (e.g. a better representation of the graph or an algorithm) ?